# Find all combinations of coefficients for an equality

Tags: python, optimization, combinations, equality, coefficients

I have a mathematical problem, and I don't know how to solve it in python.

I have the following equality:
P = ∑αi Pi

I know P and all Pi and I am looking for all αi combinations for the equality.
Besides for all αi, 0 <= αi <= 1

If you can help, it would be very great!
Thanks a lot.

I tried a brute force approach, but with a step of 0.05 for each coefficients, I am not very convinced by this method even if I increase the sampling rate and increase the tolerance of the result (I try to found the solution that is between [P-epsilon;P+epsilon] I am sure that some optimisation algorithms can suit my needs better.
I use python as programming language.

Comment: "I am looking for all αi combinations" - well, there's an infinity of solutions, so....

Comment: We need more context. Is this an exercise? Otherwise, what is the bigger picture? What are you trying to achieve here? Hard to answer without such context. First of all, there are already plenty of linear programming tool, optimization tool, OR tools, around. So reinventing the wheel makes senses only if there is a very specific context that made them unusable, or if this is a school assignment to reinvent the wheel. Secondly, as Thierry said, there are a whole infinity of solutions (a priori, depending on the numbers, a whole domain in a dimension N-1 space!). So again, there is obviously som